# Checking out google code by HTTP

Tags: http, svn

I'm trying to get some code off of google code and the message given is:

> Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over
>   HTTP. 
>   svn checkout http://ims-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ims-dev-read-only

How would I "copy anonymously over HTTP"?  If it matters, I have a Mac.

-Eric

Comment: Do you know how to checkout with username and password? Do you know how to use Subversion? Have you installed Subversion in your Mac?

Comment: I just typed svn checkout ... using terminal and the message was "Command not found".  Perhaps this means that I need to somehow install it?  (And no: I've never used Subversion before...total "noob" with regard to this aspect)

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/455214/146834 ? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html Have a nice reading! :)

Comment: Then, I'm voting to close because it's fairly obvious that you need to install a program in order to use it. This question is not going to help future visitors, which is the ultimate goal of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you'll find plenty of ways to install Subversion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/455214/where-is-svn-on-os-x-mountain-lion).  After that, just run the given command in the terminal:

```
svn checkout http://ims-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ims-dev-read-only
```

Comment: Thank you.  The link was helpful and I got it working.